# Attaching file to a record through RPC on Odoo server

Tags: java, android, odoo, attachment

[image]

In odoo 11 server you get a provision to attach a file to a record. Refer the image above. I would like to push attachments through Java RPC or any other method.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @CZoellner I have tried to use the inbuild class in odoo-mobile `IrAttachment` but no luck.

Comment: Where was the problem with that?

Comment: @CZoellner I couldn't understand how to use it.